# Tossing fair coins five times. What is the probability that it will take exactly $n$ rounds of tossing to decide?

Tags: probability

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

> Five people want to play a game of two against two. To decide who should be left out, each of the five people tosses a fair coin.
>
> If after one round of tossing, the result is one head and four tails, or one tail and four heads, the person whose outcome is different from the rest of the group is out. Otherwise, everyone tosses again.
>
> What is the probability that it will take exactly $n$th rounds of tossing to decide?

I have two questions here:

1. I listed out all the possible outcomes of the tossing are: {(H, H, H, H, H), (T, H, H, H, H), (H, T, H, H, H), (H, H, T, H, H), (H, H, H, T, H), (H, H, H, H, T), (T, T, H, H, H), (H, T, T, H, H), (H, H, T, T, H), (H, H, H, T, T), (T, T, T, H, H), (H, T, T, T, H), (H, H, T, T, T), (H, T, T, T, T), (T, H, T, T, T), (T, T, H, T, T), (T, T, T, H, T), (T, T, T, T, H), (T, T, T, T, T) } and there are 18 of these outcomes.

It has been difficult for me to figure out the total number of outcomes in many experiments without listing out them because it is not always obvious what counting method to use. In this case, I expected the total number to be $5!$, but this is obviously wrong. Please explain how to get this number correctly and quickly without having to list out all the outcomes.

2. It appears to me that this is a situation where I can apply the binomial variable. However, it seems that it is not this easy because four heads and one tail, and four tails and one head both count. Binomial variable is only applicable for either of four heads and one tail, or four tails and one head. I have a hunch that I may need to add two binomial variables (one is for getting four heads and one tail, while the other is for getting four tails and one head), but not sure if my thinking is correct.

Please help!

Comment: There should be total $32$ outcomes and not $18$.

Comment: Yes. I know I have not gotten enough outcomes. Getting the correct total number of outcomes without listing is I always have trouble with, but I have not figured out how exactly to count correctly. There are a lot of things in counting principles. 5! 2^5, combinations, permutations.... I am confused often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have missed quite a few possibilities, because at each point in time, there are $2^5 = 32$ possible outcomes (each person can either get head or tail). Of these $32$ outcomes, exactly $10$ match your criteria: either we have four heads and one tail, or four tails and head, and there are five people who can be left with the one unique value (either head or tail). The probability of ending the game in the first turn, thus equals:

$$\frac{10}{32}$$

Taking this further, to finish the game in the $n$th turn, we must fail $n - 1$ times and then get it right. Thus, the probability of finishing the game in exactly $n$ turns, equals:

$$\left(\frac{22}{32}\right)^{n - 1} \frac{10}{32}$$

Comment: Getting the correct total number of outcomes without listing is I always have trouble with.

Comment: What is the significance of the word "exactly"? What are other possible scenarios?

Comment: @AmosKu Well, other possible scenarios include all scenarios in which you require $m \neq n$ turns. Plug in $n = 4$, for example, then we find a probability of $\left(\frac{22}{32}\right)^3 \frac{10}{32} \approx 0.102$, while for $m = 3$, we find a probability of $\left(\frac{22}{32}\right)^2 \frac{10}{32} \approx 0.148$. These events are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I see. Thank you!